# Quering for a list of IDs in GE Smallworld

Tags: smallworld-gis

I'm trying to use the query builder to select a list of IDs from one layer. The problem is I've a large list of IDs. I'm working as a vendor on a client system so my access to the background database tools is limited.

Is there a way to give the query builder a list of IDs instead of using a ton of `OR` statements?

My current query is:

```sql
[dataset] objecttype WHERE id = 00001
```

I dont want to need

```sql
OR Id = 00002
OR Id = 00003
... etc
```

Is there a way to format a whole list of IDs in one line or one statement instead of using `OR` repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

You can query in SQL language as

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (id1, id2, ..., idn);
```